# Trouble reading utf-16be encoded Arabic into binary

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, arabic, utf-16

For a class that I am taking, I need to write a program that can convert files containing different sets of symbols (e.g. english alphabet, arabic alphabet) encoded in big-endian utf-16 to a file encoded in utf-8. Normally, this would be easy to do using native functions, but I have to do everything manually, as per the assignment.

Briefly, my approach has been to to read the .txt file in binary format, convert the hex code to binary, convert the binary to utf-8, and write this to file. I have been provided with a set of utf-16be files and corresponding utf-8 files to use as test cases. When I test the program I have written on an utf-16be english language file, it produces a file that is identical to the utf-8 test file.

However, when I run the same program on a utf-16be encoded file containing characters from the arabic alphabet, I've been running into trouble. More specifically, when I try to read the arabic file, rather than producing a nice set of hex codes, I get hex codes mixed with non-hex characters.

For example, when I run:

```
with open('arabic_in.txt', 'rb') as in_f:
    a_in = in_f.read()
    print a_in[:10]
```

The output is:

```
"\x06'\x06D\x06D\x06:\x06)"
```

Interestingly, I can read the same file and encode it to utf-8 with the native encoding functions and the resulting file is identical to the test file.

```
with codecs.open(utf-16_arabic_in.txt, 'rb', encoding = 'utf-16be') as    
    f_in, codecs.open(um, 'wb', encoding = 'utf-8') as o_file:

i = f_in.read()
o_file.write(i)
```

The instructor has given us permission to seek general information about reading, processing, and writing binary data. The assignment is intended to force us to work closely with encodings and develop a better understanding of how they work. Because I think the problem I am having is rooted in how I am reading the file or something related, I feel comfortable asking for help here.

I am using version 2.7.10.

Just to be clear, please do not post anything that would solve the homework problem that I have described, as that would be considered cheating. However, if you have any general insight into why I am having trouble reading the utf-16be file into binary or why the non-hex characters are in the raw data, that would be great. I know that this is not an entirely practical question, since there are already methods for automating this process. However, I would like to understand why I am not getting proper hex strings from the utf-16be file and I hope that question will have some general use for the community.

Comment: You are looking at the representation of the data - have you tried decoding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `"\x06'\x06D\x06D\x06:\x06)"` that you get is the binary representation of your `utf-16be` text(first word). so what you should now is to convert it `utf-8` :

```
 >>> a = "\x06'\x06D\x06D\x06:\x06)" 
 >>> b = unicode(a,"utf-16be") 
 >>> b # utf-8
 u'\u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0629'
 >>> print b  
 اللغة
 >>> b.encode("utf-8") # binary representation of utf-8
 '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd8\xba\xd8\xa9'
```

This word means in Arabic: The language.

Answer (score 0):

In your initial read the data

"\x06'\x06D\x06D\x06:\x06)"

Looks correct - it is Arabic - represented as 2 byte characters. You can see this more clearing using a Hex editor.

Why your data is like this - usually is because you have read the data as a BYTE string.

To convert from a set of bytes to a string object - you would encode them to the required codec.

There is a good example and explanation here

[https://pymotw.com/2/codecs/]

Use Python 3 for Unicode/Multibyte characters it is MUCH MUCH easier.